# C# string Split without array generation

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a huge string in the memory (a few hundred megabytes, there is no way I can load it partially), I wonder whether there is some easy way to split this string into lines divided by Environment.NewLine:
a) without duplicating this structure in the memory (if I use string.Split it will duplicate it)
b) with some default c# methods / minimum amount of efficient (when it comes to performance) code

Practically I would like to have a method, GetNextLineFromString.

Comment: So a StreamReader? Granted, this requires a MemoryStream over the string's bytes, but why do you have it as a string in memory in the first place?

Comment: Further to @AndrewWilliamson's comment, since the original string is so huge, you should be able to test `String.Split` memory usage pretty easily using, say, Task Manager.

Comment: @CodeCaster well I use some legacy dll that gives the result as a string

Comment: `substrings share the same memory as the original string` I don't think that is true, despite someone upvoting your comment. https://dotnetfiddle.net/4B6l91 - run this code locally and test it for yourself.

Comment: @mjwills I upvoted based on it being worth verifying, not that it was itself the answer.

Comment: Can you avoid loading the string into memory at all? is it in a file? `File.ReadLines`. A database? `SqlDataReader.GetTextReader(..)..ReadLine()`. etc.

Comment: My apologies, I'm glad someone verified that because I didn't remember correctly. I haven't found any official documentation of the `Substring` behaviour, but your answer demonstrates it pretty clearly, and I found [a warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/da0013-high-usage-of-string-split-or-string-substring?view=vs-2017) which suggests substring creates a copy of the memory

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, unfortunately, I can not avoid loading it into memory.

Comment: Why not? Do you need to process it twice? Because that's the only reason I can think of to hold anything in ram.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I get this string from legacy dll, so now way to manipulate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try *enumerating* lines, e.g.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> LinesFromString(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    yield break;

  int last = 0;

  while (true) {
    int next = value.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, last);

    if (next < 0) {
      yield return value.Substring(last);

      yield break;
    }

    yield return value.Substring(last, next - last);

    last = next + Environment.NewLine.Length;
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
string text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  "ABC", 
  "D", 
  "", // <- Empty line
  "EF"
);

Console.Write(string.Join(";", LinesFromString(text)));
```

**Outcome:**

```
ABC;D;;EF
```

If you want `N`th line you can query `text` with a help of Linq:

```
int N = 1; // N is zero-based

string line = LinesFromString(text)
  .Skip(N - 1)
  .FirstOrDefault(); // Either Nth string or null
```

**Edit:** If you use *.Net Core 3.1*, *.Net Standard 2.1* or higher you can try representing long `string` as `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` and work with *slices* of it; e.g.

```
private static IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory<char>> LinesFromMemory(ReadOnlyMemory<char> value) {
  int last = 0;

  while (true) {
    int at = value.Span.Slice(last).IndexOf(Environment.NewLine);

    if (at < 0) {
      yield return value.Slice(last);

      yield break;
    }

    yield return value.Slice(last, at);

    last += at + Environment.NewLine.Length;
  }
}
```

Then

```
string huge = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  "ABC", 
  "D", 
  "", // <- Empty line
  "EF"
);

// Note, memory is not a string, but some kind of pointer (to huge) 
foreach (var memory in LinesFromMemory(huge.AsMemory())) {
  // Let's convert memory to string and print it out
  string st = memory.ToString();

  Console.Write(st);
  Console.Write(';'); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you not save the string to a temp file, use `String.Spilt()` via a `StreamReader`, then, finally, delete the file?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-5.0 is likely simpler if you are going to write it to a file first.

Comment: Sure, agreed, @mjwills, but my point was mainly about freeing up memory if this is the main issue.